# How to solve these?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, integration, inversive-geometry

### Inverse Trigonometric Functions

They are incomplete and I don't know how to complete them.
Who can help me?

#### 1st

$$
\int\frac 1{ x \sqrt{x^{6} - 4}}dx
$$
I tried with:
$$u = x^3 $$ 
$$du= 3x^2dx$$
but this is not completed,

#### 2nd

oops, is not $$x^2$$ is only "x"
$$
\int \frac 1{ x \sqrt{x-1}}dx
$$
$$u =  \sqrt x $$ 
$$du= \frac 1{\sqrt x} dx$$
where is the sqrt(x) on du?

### 3

$$
\int \frac {e^x}{ \sqrt{4-e^x}}dx
$$
I think in this 
$$u=e^x $$
$$du = e^xdx$$
I have a bad English syntax, but I know read English++ Ok..

Comment: This is three separate problems. One problem per question is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\int\frac 1{ x \sqrt{x^{6} - 4}}dx$,
you didn't go far enough.

Write it as
$\int\frac{x^2}{ x^3 \sqrt{x^{6} - 4}}dx
$.
Make your substitution of $y = x^3$,
so $dy = 3 x^2 dx$,
and we get
$\int \frac{dy}{3 y \sqrt{y^2-4}}$
and this is essentially the same as
$\int \frac 1{ x \sqrt{x^2-1}}dx$
with $4$ instead of $1$
(but write $4$ as $2^2$).

Comment: Dear, obviously, with a **x^2** I can solve the integration, but How explain where I get it?
That's content my pedagogic guide.

Comment: @JgMc Both the numerator and denominator were multiplied by $x^2$. Multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by the same value does not change the expression.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

1. $\int\frac {dx}{ x \sqrt{x^{6} - 4}}$, let $x^6=4\sec^2 u$.
2. $\int \frac {dx}{ x \sqrt{x-1}}$, let $x=\sec^2 u$.
3. $\int \frac {e^x }{ \sqrt{4-e^x}}dx$, let $e^x=4\cos^2 u$.

---

Keep in mind these trigonometric identities: $\cos^2u + \sin^2u = 1$ and $1 + \tan^2 u = \sec^2 u$.

For $(1)$, observe that in the denominator, you have $\sqrt{x^6-4}$. Now look at the trigonometric identities, you observe that $\tan^2 u = \sec^2 u - 1$. Which is pretty similar to $x^6 - 4$. Number $(2)$ is similar.

For number $(3)$, observe that in the denominator, you have $\sqrt{4-e^x}$. Now look at the trigonometric identities, you observe that $\sin^2u = 1 - \cos^2u$, which is pretty similar to $4-e^x$.

Comment: I edited the second, was not x^2, is only x. excuse me.

Comment: @JgMc There you go.

Answer (score 0):

For $\int \frac{dx}{ x \sqrt{x^2-1}}$
let $x = \cosh(y)$,
so $\sqrt{x^2-1} = \sinh(y)$
and $dx = \sinh(y) dy$.

The integral becomes
$\int \frac{\sinh(y) dy}{\cosh(y)\sinh(y)}
=\int \frac{ dy}{\cosh(y)}
=\int \frac{2 dy}{e^y + e^{-y}}
=\int \frac{2 e^y \,dy}{e^{2y}+1}
=\int \frac{2 dz}{z^2+1}
$
with $z = e^y$.
This last is standard, so just substitute back.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I edited the second, was not x^2, is only x. excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for (3) question

Let $u=4-e^x $ ;
    $du =- e^xdx$. Substitute and integrate.